# Joomla Module Paramaters dynamic fields

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla2.5

Is there a way to get the path to the current template in a Joomla Module Parameter?

I have the folowing:

```
<field name="myimage" type="imagelist" default="" label="Select an image" directory="templates/[TEMPLATENAME]/images/" >
```

Where [TEMPLATENAME] i want to display the name of the current template to make the pathway dynamic in Joomla.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not believe there is. Not without hacking Joomla.